# Output string variable value from EditText into a message box

Tags: java, android, input, output, messagebox

I am trying to input a number into a `EditText`, then output it in a message/AlertDialog after click a button. So far I have coded up what I think should work to output it, but for some reason, it doesn't. At the moment, the only output I recieve from the message box, is the text that I specified: "saved". There is no value from the variable being displayed.
Hopefully someone will be able to see what I am doing wrong and find a solution.
Thanks

Code below:

```
Button saveBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave1);

    saveBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           EditText inputTxt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourPhoneNum);
           String phoneNum1 = inputTxt1.getText().toString();
          savenum1(phoneNum1);
       }
   });

public void savenum1(String phoneNum1) {

    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    dlgAlert.setMessage("Saved" + phoneNum1);
    //dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
    dlgAlert.create().show();

    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              //dismiss the dialog  
            }
        });  
 dlgAlert.create().show();  
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having? Are you getting an error? If so post logcat. If not then tell us what you are getting versus what you expect

Comment: sorry probably should have said. All i'm getting from the message box at the moment is "saved" no value from the variable is showing

Comment: Have you debugged to make sure that `phoneNum1` isn't blank there? Also you don't need to cast to a `String` because you are calling `toString()`

Comment: And what is this hanging out there by himself `int input`?

Comment: The edited code posted is not what i suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a private field `EditText inputTxt1;`

Before `Button saveBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave1);`
get the EditText id: `inputTxt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourPhoneNum);`

At `saveBtn1.setOnClickListener`
get the phoneNum1: `String phoneNum1 = inputTxt1.getText().toString();`
Call savenum1 with phoneNum1: `savenum1(phoneNum1);`

Remove from savenum1:
`EditText inputTxt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourPhoneNum);`
`String phoneNum1 = (String) inputTxt1.getText().toString();`

Code after correction:

```
public class SettingsScreen extends Activity {

private EditText inputTxt1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_settings);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    EditText inputTxt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourPhoneNum);    
    Button saveBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave1);

    saveBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          String phoneNum1 = inputTxt1.getText().toString();
          savenum1(phoneNum1);
       }
   });
}

public void savenum1(String phoneNum1) {

    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    dlgAlert.setMessage("Saved" + phoneNum1);
    //dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);

    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              //dismiss the dialog  
            }
        });    
    dlgAlert.create().show();
}
```

Comment: Hmmm no errors or anything but it still doesn't seem to output the number as part of the message box

Comment: It must, because I tested it and worked. See if `R.id.yourPhoneNum` is the correct EditText Id

Comment: Another thing: the OK button is not showing up. To do that `dlgAlert.create().show();` must be last line in savenum1 method

Comment: ah ha! i've got it working! thanks very much for your help, sorry for not understanding very well, i'm very new to java programming